# Sqlite: Join clause doesn't work using a View with Union All statement

Tags: join, sqlite, android-sqlite, union-all

I have a Sqlite database and I created a View *accounts_in_transactions* using Select and Union All statements as shown below:

```
CREATE VIEW accounts_in_transactions AS 
SELECT transactions_data._id,
((transactions_data.value) * -1) AS value, transactions_data.type, 
transactions_data.acc_from_id AS acc_id, 
transactions_data.acc_name_from AS acc_name
FROM transactions_data 
UNION ALL 
SELECT transactions_data._id,
transactions_data.value AS value, transactions_data.type,
transactions_data.acc_to_id AS acc_id, 
transactions_data.acc_name_to AS acc_name
FROM transactions_data;
```

I run `SELECT * FROM accounts_in_transactions;` and I get the results as expected.

But when I try to do this:

```
SELECT accounts_in_transactions.acc_id, accounts._id
FROM acounts 
JOIN accounts_in_transactions
  ON accounts._id = accounts_in_transactions.acc_id;
```

I get no result. (and *accounts._id* have the same values in *accounts_in_transactions.acc_id*)

But if I use this:

```
SELECT transactions_data.acc_from_id, transactions_data.acc_to_id , accounts._id
FROM accounts 
JOIN transactions_data
  ON accounts._id IN (transactions_data.acc_from_id,transactions_data.acc_to_id);
```

It works fine...

Is there a problem in my code, or I can't use Join in a query with a View resulted from UNION ALL statement, or is this a limitation in Sqlite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your view even work? First `SELECT 4 column, second 5 columns` (in first SELECT there is no `transactions_data.type`)

Comment: Works ok for me. What SQLite version is it? I had a similar problem with a very old version (~2006)

Comment: @lad20025 Yes it works, when I copied and paste here it missed one column. I just fixed it

Comment: @tdmsoares Please share datatypes of `accounts._id` and `accounts_in_transactions.acc_id (transactions_data.acc_from_id,transactions_data.acc_to_id)`. I guess that there is implicit conversion which trims data.

Comment: @lad2025 accounts._id is declared Integer, accounts_in_transactions.acc_id no data type declared, but only stores numbers.

Comment: @tdmsoares But `(transactions_data.acc_from_id,transactions_data.acc_to_id)` have to have datatype. Please prepare http://sqlfiddle.com, it will be much easier.

Comment: @tdmsoares Please share datatypes of `transactions_data.acc_from_id,transactions_data.acc_to_id`. Are they both `INT`?

Comment: @lad2025 Both are Integers...